# Why does this url package request receive a different response than the 'equivalent' curl request?

Tags: url

This is for [`sx.el`](https://stackapps.com/q/3950/11299), a StackExchange client for Emacs.
I'm trying to determine whether this issue is a bug in `url` or a bug in StackExchange's API.
If you need the API `key`, please get in touch with either myself or @Malabarba – we're on the [Gitter chatroom for the project](https://gitter.im/vermiculus/sx.el) pretty regularly.

The following form evaluates to two different responses depending on whether `curl` is used or whether the `url` package is used.
Since API requests are time-sensitive (and to cut down on your time investment), I've included the responses I get for the two (as parsed by `json-read-from-string` for readability's sake).

```lisp
(defconst tmp:access-token
  "YOUR ACCESS TOKEN")

(defconst tmp:key
  "YOUR API KEY")

(defun tmp:api-bug (use-curl access-token key)
  "Post a test answer to the formatting sandbox."
  (let ((random-body-1 (md5 (current-time-string)))
        (random-body-2 (md5 (md5 (current-time-string))))
        (method "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/3122/answers/add")
        (args
         (mapconcat
          #'identity
          `(,(format "access_token=%s"
                     (replace-regexp-in-string
                      "%" "%%" (url-hexify-string access-token)))
            ,(format "key=%s"
                     (replace-regexp-in-string
                      "%" "%%" (url-hexify-string key)))
            "site=meta"
            "pagesize=100"
            "filter=%%21GoYr1we0U5inG5G7wBg4JBGpbgX%%29C7LDqpy-%%2AbfwPOujOr4SR4W%%29bLNSyYUpQDdTwTj.XChTFB0gfLaAJq0hv"
            "body=this-is-an-answer-test-for-sx.el--%s")
          "&")))

    (if use-curl
        (shell-command-to-string
         (format
          "curl --silent -X POST --data %S %s | gunzip"
          (format args random-body-2)
          method))
      (let ((url-automatic-caching t)
              (url-inhibit-uncompression t)
              (url-request-data (format args random-body-1))
              (url-request-method "post")
              (url-request-extra-headers
               '(("Content-Type" . "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"))))
          (with-current-buffer
              (url-retrieve-synchronously method)
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (search-forward "\n\n")
            (delete-region (point-min) (point))
            (buffer-string))))))

(require 'json)

(json-read-from-string (tmp:api-bug t tmp:access-token tmp:key))
((total . 1)
 (page_size . 100)
 (page . 1)
 (quota_remaining . 9979)
 (quota_max . 10000)
 (has_more . :json-false)
 (items .
        [((link . "http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122//247295#247295")
          (body_markdown . "this-is-an-answer-test-for-sx.el--e3eeb6228ed9c2c58e5385b73493f0f0")
          (share_link . "http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247295/188148")
          (answer_id . 247295)
          (creation_date . 1421684370)
          (last_activity_date . 1421684370)
          (score . 0)
          (upvoted . :json-false)
          (downvoted . :json-false)
          (owner
           (display_name . "Sean Allred")
           (reputation . 160)))]))

(json-read-from-string (tmp:api-bug nil tmp:access-token tmp:key))
((total . 1)
 (page_size . 100)
 (page . 1)
 (quota_remaining . 9977)
 (quota_max . 10000)
 (has_more . :json-false)
 (items .
        [((link . "http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122//247297#247297")
          (share_link . "http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247297/188148")
          (answer_id . 247297)
          (creation_date . 1421684555)
          (last_activity_date . 1421684555)
          (score . 0)
          (owner
           (display_name . "Sean Allred")
           (reputation . 160)))]))
```

<sub>Cross-reference: https://stackapps.com/q/6083/11299</sub>

Comment: Could this be related to `user-agent` or cookies?

Comment: @abo-abo I'm unfortunately unfamiliar with most web stuff. I've very much hacked this together (with a lot of help from [@Jonathan](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/337/jonathan-leech-pepin)), so I'm still learning about all this stuff.  There is no mention of `user agent` in the variables given by `url`.

Comment: I'm not a pro either, but I know that websites can give different responses, depending on `user-agent`. Most tools can spoof it. And `url-retrieve` has a `inhibit-cookies` option, so at least in some cases this could be relevant.

Comment: @abo-abo I just tried, and the cookies option makes no difference.

Comment: Did you try `url-user-agent` and http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/curl/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annoyingly, the problem was here: `(url-request-method "post")`.

Changing that to `(url-request-method "POST")` fixes everything.